# Creating a "Tree" of Commands from ListView

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a set of classes that allow me to make a "Tree of Commands" that my application will execute.  The commands are initially put into a Details `List View` which will then be parsed via `for each` loop (command is assigned to the `.Tag` property) and then added to the execution script which will be serialized into XML.  Here is a logic example of what I mean:

```
        EXAMPLE: Expected Input from ListView
        >Command - Do Something (Line 1)
        >Command - Do Something (Line 2)
        >Command - Loop (Line 3)
        >Command - Do Something (Line 4)
        >Command - Do Something (Line 5)
        >Command - End Loop (Line 6)
        >Command - Do Something (Line 7)

        EXAMPLE: Expected Class Output (For Serialization)
        >Command - Do Something (Line 1)
        >Command - Do Something (Line 2)
        >Command - Loop (Line 3)
                >Command - Do Something (Line 4) (Child to Line 3)
                >Command - Do Something (Line 5) (Child to Line 3)
        >Command - End Loop (Line 6)
        >Command - Do Something (Line 7)

        EXAMPLE: Expected Input from ListView
        >Command - Loop (Line 1)
        >Command - Do Something (Line 2)
        >Command - Loop (Line 3)
        >Command - Do Something (Line 4)
        >Command - End Loop (Line 5)
        >Command - End Loop (Line 6)

        EXAMPLE: Expected Class Output (For Serialization)
        >Command - Loop (Line 1)
                >Command - Do Something (Line 2) (Child to Line 1)
                >Command - Loop (Line 3) (Child to Line 1)
                        >Command - Do Something (Line 4) (Child to Line 3)
                >Command - End Loop (Line 5) (Child to Line 1)
        >Command - End Loop (Line 6)
```

Here is the code that I have:

```
public class ExecutionScript
{
//the Execution Script class will be serialized to XML
List<ExecutionCommand> ExecutionCommands;
public ExecutionScript()
{
    ExecutionCommands = new List<ExecutionCommand>();
}
public ExecutionCommand AddNewParentCommand(ExecutionInfo executionInfo)
{
    ExecutionCommand newExecutionCommand = new ExecutionCommand() { ParentCommand = executionInfo };
    ExecutionCommands.Add(newExecutionCommand);
    return newExecutionCommand;
}
}
public class ExecutionInfo
{
//the Execution Info class contains information about the command
public string CommandName { get; set; }
}

public class ExecutionCommand
{
//the Execution Command class helps expand together
public ExecutionInfo ParentCommand { get; set; }
public List<ExecutionCommand> ChildCommands { get; set; }
public ExecutionCommand()
{
    ChildCommands = new List<ExecutionCommand>();
}
public ExecutionCommand AddSubCommand(ExecutionInfo executionInfo)
{
    ExecutionCommand newExecutionCommand = new ExecutionCommand() { ParentCommand = executionInfo };
    ChildCommands.Add(newExecutionCommand);
    return newExecutionCommand;
}
}
```

The class setup seems kind of clunky and awkward - there is probably a smarter way to structure it.  Given the example above, here is how I would instantiate and setup the class manually (this should be done eventually automatically).

```
       //because I know where to expect children:
        ExecutionScript newScript = new ExecutionScript();
        newScript.AddNewParentCommand(new ExecutionInfo() { CommandName = "Command (Line 1)" });
        newScript.AddNewParentCommand(new ExecutionInfo() { CommandName = "Command (Line 2)" });
         var loopCommand = newScript.AddNewParentCommand(new ExecutionInfo() { CommandName = "Loop (Line 3)" });
        loopCommand.AddSubCommand(new ExecutionInfo() { CommandName = "Command (Line 4)" });
        loopCommand.AddSubCommand(new ExecutionInfo() { CommandName = "Command (Line 5)" });
        newScript.AddNewParentCommand(new ExecutionInfo() { CommandName = "Command (Line 6)" });
        newScript.AddNewParentCommand(new ExecutionInfo() { CommandName = "Command (Line 7)" });
```

Is there a way to simplify the classes so that it becomes a closer representation of a treeview than what I have?  How could I use recursion to build the `ExecutionScript`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe composite pattern would be useful here

```
public static void Main()
    {
        ExecutionComposite composite = new ExecutionComposite(new ExecutionInfo() {CommandName = string.Empty});
        composite.Add(new ExecutionOne(new ExecutionInfo() {CommandName = "Command (Line 1)"}));
        composite.Add(new ExecutionOne(new ExecutionInfo() {CommandName = "Command (Line 2)"}));

        ExecutionComposite composite1 = new ExecutionComposite(new ExecutionInfo() {CommandName = "Loop (Line 3)"});
        composite.Add(composite1);
        composite1.Add(new ExecutionOne(new ExecutionInfo() {CommandName = "Command (Line 4)"}));
        composite1.Add(new ExecutionOne(new ExecutionInfo() {CommandName = "Command (Line 5)"}));

        ExecutionComposite composite2 = new ExecutionComposite(new ExecutionInfo() { CommandName = "Loop (Line 5)" });
        composite1.Add(composite2);
        composite2.Add(new ExecutionOne(new ExecutionInfo() { CommandName = "Command (Line 6)" }));
        composite2.Add(new ExecutionOne(new ExecutionInfo() { CommandName = "Command (Line 7)" }));

        composite.Add(new ExecutionOne(new ExecutionInfo() {CommandName = "Command (Line 8)"}));
        composite.Add(new ExecutionOne(new ExecutionInfo() {CommandName = "Command (Line 9)"}));

        composite.Print("--");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public interface IExection
{
    ExecutionInfo Info { get; }
    void Print(string indent);
}

public class ExecutionComposite : IExection
{
    List<IExection> executions = new List<IExection>();

    public ExecutionInfo Info { get; }

    public ExecutionComposite(ExecutionInfo executionInfo)
    {
        Info = executionInfo;
    }

    public void Add(IExection one)
    {
        executions.Add(one);
    }

    public void Remove(IExection one)
    {
        if (executions.Contains(one))
        {
            executions.Remove(one);
        }
    }

    public void Print(string indent)
    {
        indent += "\t";
        foreach (var exe in executions)
        {
            exe.Print(indent);
        }
    }
}

public class ExecutionOne : IExection
{
    public ExecutionInfo Info { get; }

    public ExecutionOne(ExecutionInfo executionInfo)
    {
        Info = executionInfo;
    }

    public void Print(string indent)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", indent, Info.CommandName);
    }
}

public class ExecutionInfo
{
    //the Execution Info class contains information about the command
    public string CommandName { get; set; }
}
```